# Extension of Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus

I'd like to prove: Given two points A and B and a straight line connecting them AB, any smooth curve passing through A and B will, at some point, have a derivative that exceeds the slope of AB.

My proof uses the Mean Value Theorem. So, any curve passing through A and B has, at some point, a derivative equal to slope of AB, call this point C. Consider lines AC and BC. Together with AB, they form a triangle. Noting the angles a and b, we know that the slope of either AC or BC exceeds the slope of AB, and, by the Mean Value Theorem, there exists a derivative on any curve passing through either A and C or through B and C that equals the slopes of the lines AC and BC. Therefore, any smooth curve passing through A and B will, at some point, have a derivative that exceeds the slope of AB.

Perhaps this is trivial, but for me it is important.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Any thoughts on this proof?

Comment: The statement you are trying to prove is correct along with the procedure you have derived to achieve the claim, however there is the edge case of the smooth curve being the straight line AB itself. In that case there would not exist any point where the derivative exceeds the slope of the line AB since the curve is AB itself. so you should probably explicitly exclude this from the set of smooth functions you are trying to prove this over to avoid being inaccurate.

Comment: Another method to overcome this edge case is to use slack inequality instead of a strict one. Then it is universally applicable.